# How can I use Lucid's Virtu with Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

While tromping through the [ATI Catalyst driver problem](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4876967911) I had the sudden insight that I shouldn't be using my ATI card (an aged Radeon HD 4300 series) at all but rather the Intel HD option provided by my i7-2600k processor.

When I right clicked on the Diablo 3 icon there was no option to "Run with Virtu" as I had seen with Mass Effect 3 and other titles.

What is the correct method for getting Virtu to take over and give me a graphics boost?

Comment: Possible more suitable at http://superuser.com ? I don't know, I'm just suggesting that you might get a better answer from there.

Comment: @Jasarien I haven't had success with questions about Virtu on superuser.com  If I don't get an answer here, I'll post my own experiences tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the Lucid Virtu control panel, there is an 'Applications' tab. I added the path to "Diablo III.exe", then selected the "D" column as well as checked the "H" box.

I think D is for Discrete graphics (your Radeon) and I is for Integrated (the Intel HD). H is probably the Lucid "Hyperformance", which is supposed to let both cards work together.

So, for what you're asking: Select the I button and don't check the H box. If I'm understanding it right, that should make Virtu run only on your Intel HD graphics.